# How do I convert the output from ls to columns or a table? (Preferably "filelessly")

Tags: multiple-columns, ls

Say I have a folder with a range input/output files and I want to put the input-files in one column and the output-files in another column next to the first to compare them:

```
$ ls
input1.inp  input10.inp  input2.inp  input3.inp  input4.inp  input5.inp  
input6.inp  input7.inp  input8.inp  input9.inp  output1.dat  output10.dat  
output2.dat  output3.dat  output4.dat  output5.dat  output6.dat  output7.dat  
output8.dat  output9.dat
```

And I would like the output as:

```
input1.inp    output1.dat
input10.inp   output10.dat
input2.inp    output2.dat
input3.inp    output3.dat
input4.inp    output4.dat
input5.inp    output5.dat
input6.inp    output6.dat
input7.inp    output7.dat
input8.inp    output8.dat
input9.inp    output9.dat
```

I assume this can be done using a combination of `ls` and `columns`or some other programs/tools. I just can't figure out a good combination of commands and/or pipes/redirects. I figured that I could achieve this with `vimdiff`

```
vimdiff <(ls -1 *.inp) <(ls -1 *.dat)
```

Though I'd prefer getting the output printed directly on screen (stdout(?)).

Well, slightly embarrassed and a few "doh" moments later, I am closer but not quite there. So, using `paste` I am able to get pretty close to what I want:

```
paste <(ls -1 *.inp) <(ls -1 *.dat)
```

This works as long as input and output filenames correlate as in the example and are produced "in order".

```
input1.inp    output1.dat
input10.inp   output10.dat
...           ...
...           ...
input7.inp    output7.dat
    input8.inp
    input9.inp
```

However, if there are a mismatch in the order, one column gets shifted and "matches" don't line up.

```
input1.inp    output1.dat
input10.inp   output10.dat
...           ...
...           ...
inputX.inp    output7.dat
input7.inp    
    input8.inp
    input9.inp
```

The same is obviously observed with:

```
diff -y <(ls -1 *.inp) <(ls -1 *.dat)
```

Obviously, aligning the outputs is a bigger issue than I imagined as the filenames are different with either different prefix or suffix. Hence, every "line" is different when using `diff`.

I am going to close this topic as I have something that works right now, just not exactly how I'd imagined it. Though I'll leave it open for a little while longer as just to see of anyone has any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Either `paste <(ls -1 *.inp) <(ls -1 *.dat)` or `diff -y <(ls -1 *.inp) <(ls -1 *.dat)` did what I was asking for. Then I ended up wanting even more...

Still, the original problem was solved using either solution and I am happy with it for now.